# Mysql resolving 127.0.0.1 to hostname

Tags: dns, mysql

I'm trying to connect to mysql using the command

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1
```

It comes up with the error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'mydomain.com' (using password: NO)
```

Why is 127.0.0.1 being converted into my domain name, and how can I fix it?
If I use skip-name-resolve, then instead of "mydomain.com" it uses the external IP.

Also, it does work when using localhost socket, but not localhost TCP.

I have `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` in my.cnf and the only thing in `/etc/hosts` is `127.0.0.1 localhost`

**Edit**: On Ubuntu 13.04, and MySQL 5.5.34